# react fetch to spring @ResourceMapping method not called with the same request parameters

Tags: javascript, java, spring, reactjs, fetch

I am developing a bookmark web application that stores website bookmarks and folders of bookmarks. It is written using React with Spring on the back end. I am storing the bookmarks as json in a PostgreSQL database. However I noticed that each time I pass the same request parameters to my @ResourceMapping method the method is only called and returned the first time. For example if I delete one bookmark the method is called the updated json is returned but if I repeat that action and the same parameters are passed the method is not called.

Here is my delete button event handler

```html
handleDeleteClick(e) {
     if (e === 1) {
     console.log(this.props.id)
       removeBookmark(RemoveBookmarkURL, "root", this.props.id)
         .then(data => {
           console.log(
           this.props.onClick(1, data, 0)
           })
           .catch(error => {})
     }
     this.setState({ remove: false })
}
```

Here is my fetch request

```html
function removeBookmark(feedUrl, folder, loc) {
   let url = new URL(window.location.origin + feedUrl) 
   
   url.searchParams.append("folder", folder)
   url.searchParams.append("bookmarkLocation", loc)
 
   return fetch(url, {
     credentials: "include",
     method: "POST",
     header: { Accept: "application/json" }
   })
     .then(response => {
       return response.json()
     })
     .then(data => {
       return data
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.error(error)
       return error
     })
}
```

Here is my java method

```
  @ResourceMapping(value = "removeBookmark")
  public ModelAndView removeBookmarkData(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) {
     ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("json");
     Map<String, String> userInfo = (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(PortletRequest.USER_INFO);
     String pidm = userInfo.get("pidm");

     String folder = request.getParameter("folder");
     String bookmarkLoc = request.getParameter("bookmarkLocation");
     String location = "{" + folder + ", " + bookmarkLoc + "}";

     logger.error(folder);
     logger.error(location);

     int i = jdbcTemplate.update(Constants.REMOVE(), new Object[] {location, pidm});
     logger.error(i);
     String bookmarks = getData(pidm);

     model.addObject("bookmarks", bookmarks);

     return model;
 }
```

}

Here is my sql and a sample of the json data

```
update bookmarks set data = data #- ?::text[] where owner = ?

{"root":[{"name":"stackoverflow","url":"http://stackoverflow.com", "description": "online coding community", "created_at":"2017-05-03"},{"name":"postgres","url":"http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-inner-join/", "description": "online coding community", "created_at":"2017-05-03"}],"sample":[{"name":"stackoverflow","url":"http://stackoverflow.com",  "description": "online coding community", "created_at":"2017-05-03"},{"name":"w3schools","url":"https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp",  "description": "online coding community","created_at":"2017-05-03"}, {"name":"gmail","url":"https://mail.google.com",  "description": "e-mail", "created_at":"2017-05-03"}]}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a caching issue instead of being an issue with my method of handling requests. The response was caching data and in turn causing issues when that data was updated. The solution was to set the expiration time in the response to 0. Here's the code that fixed the issue. ->

```
response.reset();
response.getCacheControl().setExpirationTime(0);
```